# Fetching value in the json array in MySQL, Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have that kinda table and data :

```
Table Name : data

+------+-----------------+--------+----------+
| id   | number          | name   | surname  |
+------+-----------------+--------+----------+
|    1 | [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] |   John |      Doe |
|    2 | [1, 2, 4, 8]    |  James |     Webb |
|    3 | [3, 4, 5]       |  Jenny |     Test |
+------+-----------------+--------+----------+
```

For example, I want to fetch the rows in the `number` column with the value `3` :

```
+------+-----------------+--------+----------+
| id   | number          | name   | surname  |
+------+-----------------+--------+----------+
|    1 | [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] |   John |      Doe |
|    3 | [3, 4, 5]       |  Jenny |     Test |
+------+-----------------+--------+----------+
```

I tried that with Laravel but didn't work. :

```
DB::table('data')
            ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?, number)', [3])
            ->get();
```

How can I solve that problem? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: what is data type of number column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks for your answers. I found the answer to my question as follows :**

I made the Array values as strings. Like that :

```
Table Name : data

+------+---------------------------+--------+----------+
| id   | number                    | name   | surname  |
+------+---------------------------+--------+----------+
|    1 | ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] |   John |      Doe |
|    2 | ["1", "2", "4", "8"]      |  James |     Webb |
|    3 | ["3", "4", "5"]           |  Jenny |     Test |
+------+---------------------------+--------+----------+
```

And then I used to this codes. :

```
 $_data = DB::table('data')
            ->where('number', 'LIKE', '%"' . "3" . '"%')
            ->get();
```

Also you can do with SQL commands. Like that :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM data
  WHERE number LIKE '%"3"%';
```

Exactly like I want, it turned to me this :

```
+------+---------------------------+--------+----------+
| id   | number                    | name   | surname  |
+------+---------------------------+--------+----------+
|    1 | ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] |   John |      Doe |
|    3 | ["3", "4", "5"]           |  Jenny |     Test |
+------+---------------------------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toJson(), to convert the collection to json object in Laravel.

```
$_data = DB::table('data')
            ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?, number)', [3])
            ->get()->toJson();
dd($_data);
```

Have a look at the [documentation] https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#json-responses

Comment: Thank you for your answering but it didn't work. It turned `^ "[]"`

Comment: first check your query response and after apply ->toJson(); end of your collection query - as per laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json

Comment: another way 
`$_data = DB::table('data')->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?, number)', [3])->get();
var_dump(json_decode($_data));`

Comment: Thank you for all. I found the questions answer. :) @Kalpesh Gamit